# Pandas - if condition with lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

This works:

```
C = df_temp['For Team'].map(
            lambda x: df_teams.loc[df_teams['CommentName']==x,'TeamColor'].item())
```

But I would like to add a condition to `lambda` of x being in another list 'y', like so:

```
y = ['salah', 'zico', 'pele']
```

I've tried:

```
lambda x: df_teams.loc[df_teams['CommentName']==x if x in y,'TeamColor'].item())
```

But this raises invalid syntax.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `isin`

```
df_teams.loc[df_teams['CommentName'].isin(y),'TeamColor'].item()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
C = df_temp['For Team'].map(lambda x: df_teams.loc[df_teams['CommentName']==x and x in y,'TeamColor'].item())
```

You need to join both conditions with an "and" instead of adding an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a named function first and, then, apply that on lambdas.

```py
y = ["salah", "zico", "pele"]


def get_teamcolor(x, y):
    if x in y:
        return df_teams.loc[df_teams["CommentName"] == x, "TeamColor"].item()


C = df_temp["For Team"].map(lambda x: get_teamcolor(x, y))
```